# Extract link from HTML source Swift

Tags: html, ios, iphone, swift

I have want to extract a link from a website. I have retrieved the HTML for the website using the following code:

```
let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOfURL: myURL)
```

And giving the output of:

```
...
<div class="map-overlay-box">
<a href="{directions_link}" target="_blank" class="store-info self clear">
...
```

I want to find the {directions_link} part of the webpage. I am able to see the link when I go onto Safari and inspect element, but in my application it is just replaced with that placeholder.

I have attempted to use `Kanna` ([see here](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna)) like so, but I have no result:

```
if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: myHTMLString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
     for link in doc.xpath("//div[@class='map-overlay-box']") {
          print(link.text)
          print(link["href"])
     }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

XPath doesn't have a native equivalent of a CSS class selector.

Try the following **xpath**:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'map-overlay-box')]
```

To exclude you work with dynamically HTML generated by javascript, try to make a test with your output:

```
let myHTMLString = "<div class=\"map-overlay-box\"><a href=\"{directions_link}\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"store-info self clear\"></a></div>"
```

If your HTML is generated dynamically keep in mind you have also `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to help you to interpretate JS and obtain your html strings..

Comment: Still does not print out anything

Comment: The output you recevied is a static HTML? Or dinamically generated by javascript? Try to make your own output with let htmlOutput="<div class..." just to make a test..

Comment: I used the following but "Hello" did not print: `for link in doc.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'map-overlay-box')]") {
                    print("HELLO") }`

Comment: I just used  `let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOfURL: myURL) ` to achieve the HTML

Comment: Ok using the test myHTMLString the xpath works, but how would I get the right HTML from the webpage then?

Comment: first of all put a print("my html string: \(myHTMLString)") after if let doc. Then, if it's blank you use dinamically html, your html doesnt exist until javascript create it, so the best way is to analyze javascript ed execute it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110401/discussion-between-alexander-macleod-and-alessandro-ornano).